# How to overlay text on image using swift?

Tags: swift, uiimage

First of all, I am using Auto Layout for this Swift application. In one view, i have an image that scales to full screen. And over this image there is an overlay text.

The problem is; When opening in iPhone6, the image scales and fits nicely but the text misplaces (normally) on the image, since the constraints are still the same.

I was thinking of merging the text and the image into one image layer so they scale and fit together. Is this possible ?

Or, anyone knows any other solution rather than trying to understand device and changing text placement contstraints accordingly ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using auto layout for display text in Lable. than must you have to play with constrain from interface builder. share you screenshot